# Триггер Before в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

начал изучать синтаксис MS SQL и столкнулся с одной не понятной ситуацией (до этого изучал Oracle, PostgreSQL). В двух последних имеются триггеры как: AFTER, BEFORE, INSTEAD. Когда как в MS SQL только AFTER, INSTEAD. Если я хочу, чтобы мой триггер сработал до выполнения операции, а не после как мне нужно указать это в триггере ?

Если возможно с маленьким примером. Буду очень благодарен за пояснения, так как хочу изучить синтаксис MS SQL.

Comment: Либо использовать after и откатывать, если условия нарушены, либо instead of и накатывать, если выполняются.

Comment: INSTEAD мало чем отличается от BEFORE, если при завершении последнего инициировать выполнение той же операции.